# Time consuming server request via ajax delays browser navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC website.

The website works like this: A customer logs into the website, and he or she sees a dashboard with graphs showing customer data. The data shown in the graphs are fetched from the server via ajax, like this:

```
$.getJSON(_dataurl, function (data) {
  // data is what is shown in the graphs
}
```

This calls my controller:

```
[Route("CustomerUsage/UsageData")]
public async Task<JsonResult> UsageData()
{
   // Fetches graph data - very time consuming in some cases.
}
```

Fetching graph data for a customer can take up to 10 seconds. Unfortunately, this is not something I can change.

The problem is that while the browser waits for the controller to return with data, if the user navigates to a different page from the menu, the server doesn't respond to that request until it has finished returning graph data.

Is there anything I can do about this, so that the browser allows to navigate to a different page even though it still hasn't returned from the first call to the controller?

Comment: did you set up async to false ?

Comment: @madalinivascu No, I didn't change the default settings.

Comment: what do you mean by `doesn't respond to that request` how does it not respond?

Comment: @madalinivascu: I mean it waits for the graph data to be returned, before it allows to navigate to a different page. However, I can see in the browser that it has registered the click to go to a different page (says "waiting for localhost" in browser status bar). But again it doesn't leave the page until ajax call has returned with graph data.

Comment: when you do $.getJSON is the page refreshing ?

Comment: @madalinivascu: the call is made when the dashboard page loads (on a document ready event).

Comment: if its on page load why are you using ajax?

Comment: @madalinivascu: it's for the dashboard page to show quickly, and then fill the graphs with data afterwards.